# AWS Lambda function with DynamoDB - put and putItem not adding item to table

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use Lambda functions for a basic database API, with calls to be made directly to each Lambda function via its function URL.

It's working perfectly for getting a database item by its id, but when I try to use put instead, the item isn't added to the table.

I've tried multiple different methods and examples, but haven't been able to get any of them working. With some examples from AWS documentation and other guides/threads, I had various 502 errors and issues with node version, import vs. require etc.

With others, the function runs fine without errors but the item simply isn't added to the DynamoDB table. The execution role of the Lambda function has DynamoDBFullAccess (in fact, I gave it all policies with DynamoDB in the name).

I would really appreciate a solution that isn't just a code snippet, but includes information on setting up the function, e.g. which node version the code is for, and the complete code including imports and exports.

The working Lambda function for getting an item by id:

```
const AWS = require ('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
exports.handler = async (event) => {
 
 const id = +event.queryStringParameters.id
 
 const params = {
  TableName: "test",
  Key: {
     "id": id
  }
 };

 const data = await dynamoDb.get(params).promise();
 
 const response = {}
 
 if ((typeof data) === "object") {
  response.statusCode = 200;
  response.body = JSON.stringify(data);
 } else {
  response.statusCode = 500;
 }
 return response;
};
```

An attempt using put. This returns an empty object with a 200 status code, as expected, but the hardcoded item is not added to the table 'test'. No errors in CloudWatch at all.

```
const AWS = require ('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
exports.handler = async (event) => {
 
 const params = {
  TableName: "test",
  Item: {
     "id": 1
  }
 };

 const data = await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
 
 const response = {}
 
 if ((typeof data) === "object") {
  response.statusCode = 200;
  response.body = JSON.stringify(data);
 } else {
  response.statusCode = 500;
 }
 return response;
};
```

Comment: Code looks reasonable. How are you determining that the item was not written? Any chance you are looking at a table named test in the wrong AWS region?

Comment: You are definitely thinking along the right lines! I was checking the item count of the table, luckily I stumbled onto a resource that mentioned that the item count takes 6 hours to update... Went to explore table items and there are all my items! Woops... I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone else who might be making the same mistake. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Also, note that when you call put, if an item with the same primary key already exists, then that item will simply be replaced. The (eventual) item count won't change. It's not clear that the accepted answer is actually the answer tbh, despite the fact that it's helpful in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always wrap async methods in try/catch blocks to expose any exceptions.

Regardless, it looks like your GetItem uses a String as `id` whereas your PutItem uses a number.

Ensure you are using the correct data type and add the try/catch and your issue should be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my problem was simple user error, as usual! I was checking the table's item count to see if the item had been posted, without realising the item count takes 6 hours to update. The items had in fact been posting after all!

Comment: /facepalm. this was exactly my problem, too. GG AWS for having a god awful interface

Comment: Note that if you visit DynamoDB > MyTable > MyTable detail there's a "Get live item count" button in the Items Summary tab. If you press that, you get an interface where you can request a live item count.